# read file having columns in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

How do I read a file (text or csv) having columns in bash script ?
I used awk.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' file_name.txt
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there any other way to do so.

Comment: How does your file look like? comma separated or tab-separated

Comment: Your line assumes that file_name.txt contains whitespace (tabs, spaces) as delimiter. If your file contains "," then you need to tell awk to use "," as a delimiter instead. You do this with the -F option: `awk -F, '{print ... `.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'd use IFS modification in conjunction with while and read, as in

```
... | while IFS=$';' read a b c; do ... done
```

Comment: You don't need `$` for setting `IFS` to `;` here, they are used only when defining ANSI escape sequences like `\n` or `\t`

Comment: @Inian Are you sure, for the semicolon ? I've just tested without and with the `$` and first doesn't work where second does. Hum intermediate syntax `IFS=';'`

Comment: That is what I meant too, `IFS=';'` should be sufficient

Comment: @Inian it is not necessary, but showing here the fuller syntax is nice to remember how to manage sequences you mentionned